# General term of sequence related

Tags: sequences-and-series

Whats is the general term of the sequence for each value of $n$ corresponding to the value of $f_n$ (total $18$ values are given of $n$ and $f_n$ each)

$n$   = | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 | 15 | 16 | 17 | 18 |

$f_n$= | 1 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 6 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 8 | 8 |

Comment: The value of $f_n$ has a formula depending on $n \mod{4}$. Can you see  it?

Comment: All that i can see is $2$ is repeating thrice, then you have $3$, $4$ is repeating thrice, then you have $5$, $6$ is repeating thrice, then you have $7$.. I do not know what it is

Comment: Crostul gave you a fine hint. See too [OEIS A004524](https://oeis.org/A004524) for a closed form : $$f_n=\lfloor n/4\rfloor+\lfloor (n+1)/4\rfloor$$

Comment: Thank you very much  Raymond Manzoni  Sir. your answer is absolutely worth.

Comment: Glad it helped @kalpeshmpopat.